# How to move NA to the top of the column of an R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

How i can move all the `NA` to the top of the column `F` of the `DF` data.frame. I don't want to move its corresponding `Dates`, just the `NA` to the top of `column` of `F`.

```
set.seed(1500)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2003-12-31"), by="day"),
                      A = runif(1095, 0,10),
                      D = runif(1095,5,15),
                      F = c(runif(1000,3,5), rep(NA, 95)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, something like this?

```
DF$F <- c(rep(NA, sum(is.na(DF$F))), na.omit(DF$F))
```

Add all the `NA`'s first and then append all the non-NA values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order` with `is.na` to bring `NA` to the top.

```
DF$F <- DF$F[order(!is.na(DF$F))]
```

Or you use only `is.na` one as it is and one as negation.

```
i <- is.na(DF$F)
DF$F <- c(DF$F[i], DF$F[!i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all NA's are at the end, we can *shift*:

```
x <- c(1:5, c(NA, NA))
x
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA

data.table::shift(x, sum(is.na(x)))
# [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Or as column *F* is not related to other columns, just reverse it:

```
rev(x)
# [1] NA NA  5  4  3  2  1
```